# "} expected" on a seemingly completely statment

Tags: java

I have a String[] that I want to pass to a process. For some odd reason, my IDE is giving me the error that a brace is expected and my statement is not a complete statement. I've checked everywhere in my code and I don't see a single brace out of place, so I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error. Here is the code:

```
String[] cmdArray4 = {"/bin/tcsh","-c","sed -e 's/SPACE/"+matlab1spacing+"/' -e 's/MAX/"+matlab1dmax+"/' -e 's/NAME/"+matlab1filename"/' /filepath/matlabscript1.m > /filepath/matlabscript2.m"};
Process passVarstoMatlab;
passVarstoMatlab = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray4);
```

I tried escaping the single-quote characters to see if perhaps that was the problem, but this did not make a difference. What is even more confusing is that I have a very similar-formatted String[] in a different method which works perfectly fine. Here is that String[], which I used as reference:

```
String[] cmdArray3 = {"/bin/tcsh","-c", "sed -e 's/AAA/"+newFirstLine+"/' -e 's/BBB/"+newCntr+"/' -e 's/SPACE/"+newSpacing+"/' -e 's/MAX/"+newDmax+"/' /filepath/gnom_Dmax_scan.pl > /filepath/g2.pl"};
```

Maybe there is some small error that I'm not seeing, so I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Your example looks fine to me - and given that cmdArray3 works, I think the problem is actually somewhere *else* in the same file.  When there are mismatched brackets/braces, parsers are often bad at guessing where the missing brace should be.  (Which is fair enough, since by definition it can't tell which closing brace "belongs to" which opening brace.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
 +matlab1filename"/'
```

Try this:

```
String[] cmdArray4 = {"/bin/tcsh","-c","sed -e 's/SPACE/"+matlab1spacing+"/' -e 's/MAX/"+matlab1dmax+"/' -e 's/NAME/"+matlab1filename+"/' /filepath/matlabscript1.m > /filepath/matlabscript2.m"};
```

Comment: I knew it was something small. Thanks.

Comment: +1 your answer is more thorough then mine, but better late than never eh ;-)

Comment: +1 for yours as well. Looks like we were both attacking the problem at the same time ;)

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a + after matlab1filename